# Does persistently masturbating cause weight loss?

Tags: weight-loss, body-weight, testosterone, liquids, masturbation

Alright, I will just get it laid out as fast as I can: I masturbate a lot  to the point of ridiculousness (average 8-10 times a day (especially when projects are due, or I need to get stuff done)) and the typical semen amount is 1.5 teaspoons. According to my calculations, this can drop a load up to 2.5 pounds a week. I have already planned for the protein *output*. Will this make me hungrier or otherwise not work in shaving off weight?

Comment: Why should this be deleted? Seems like a reasonable question for every man and male teenager. It's pretty useful to know what exactly happens while masturbating.

Comment: `According to my calculations` -- I'd have to see those calculations to believe it. I'm extremely skeptical that you ejaculate 7000 kilocalories worth of semen per week, which is what it would take to lose 2 pounds per week. Water loss doesn't count since your body will promptly replace it.

Comment: Oh, I did not take water concentration into account. Does anyone know how much water is in it? Looks like I will have to into experimental phase.